# Передать указатель на массив указателей

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

У меня есть конструктор в классе, который как аргумент должен принимать указатель на массив указателей.

```
 Figure *board_m[8][8];

 board_m[x][y] = new Swan(color, *&board_m);


 Swan(Figure flashboard[8][8]) {
    board_mp = &flashboard;
    cout<< "Swan on desck" <<endl;
}
```

Как сделать чтобы board_mp было указателем на массив указателей.
P.S.Заранее извиняюсь если написал полную ахинею в вопросе

Comment: В интеренете есть куча ресурсов про указатели на указатели, как они обозначаются и как они работают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя массива указывает на его первый элемент ([Пример](https://ideone.com/7qGq4H)). Можно записать указатель на массив указателей так:

```
Figure (*board_m)[8]; //стоит соблюдать приоритет операций

Swan(Figure flashboard[8][8]) {
    board_mp = flashboard;
    cout<< "Swan on desck" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Однако имя массива не является указателем на его первый элемент, а в этой записи `flashboard` не является массивом.